# How to handle and render more than one api responses contain more than 5000 array of string in component

Tags: reactjs

On form submit, I am calling more than 1 APIs parallelly which return the huge amount of data (approx 6-10 thousand strings in array on each api call)
in json format and after that I need to display these records in the different different bootstrap cards as a list of checkbox.

Can anyone please guide me how and where to store the response data and how render that in bootstrap card which is a reactjs component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Approach 1:** Using simple API calls

You can use simple API calls get the data and hold this data in your Components **State**, may use an array and push the response on to the Array in State.

> **Approach 2:** Using REDUX to hold the state (If you need global access of the data)

You can use [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) Middleware and use an **[Asynchronous Action Creator](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions)** to fire and get the data and have a **[Synchronous Action Creator](https://redux.js.org/advanced/async-actions)** in its callback to update the store using a reducer.

The concept is the same only difference is now the data can be accessed anywhere using [Connect](https://blog.logrocket.com/react-redux-connect-when-and-how-to-use-it-f2a1edab2013?gi=a875f083ed63)

> **Recomendation:** Try not to load full data if possible

Load only data which is in the visibility scope of the user and use [Lazy Loading](https://hackernoon.com/lazy-loading-and-preloading-components-in-react-16-6-804de091c82d)

Comment: Thanks for replying Praveen!
I have created a state object to store the all APIs responses in this using for loop:

t1: {
      arr: [
        {
          cardname: "",
          count: 0,
          responsedataArr: []
        }
      ]
    }

Can you please let me know how can I update this state. Suppose I need to run the for loop 3 times, and calling the api in loop and then will be pushing the response in state arr. so that I can use this state to render the records.

Comment: After getting the response from API, map through your result set and push values into this variable array, then once done, use setState({responsedataArr:valueArr})